# Why the ontap property of gesture detector is not working on a second consecutive tap in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, gesturedetector, ontap

(ie, ontap > navigation happens > back click, again ontap > no navigation)

```
             GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => model.navigateToSetting(),
                      child: ListTile(
                        
                        title: Text(
                          'Settings',
                          semanticsLabel: 'Settings',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .primaryTextTheme
                              .headline6!
                              .copyWith(
                                fontSize: 22.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Notifications, Feedback, App Info, Terms & Privacy Policy, Logout',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .subtitle2!
                              .copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  fontSize: 15),
                          semanticsLabel:
                              'Notifications, Feedback, App Info, Terms & Privacy Policy, Logout',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see if onTap is being called?

Answer (score 0):

GestureDetector may not be working because it also has a double click function.